# Сжать/уменьшить файл перед отправкой на сервер

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я делаю приложение на js, и как одно из функций приложения - загрузка фотографий.
Можно ли как то сжать эту фотографию перед отправкой на сервер?
Я нашел вот этот вот скрипт - https://github.com/gokercebeci/canvasResize , но теперь не знаю, как заменить уже выбранный пользователем файл на сжатый...

Мой js код:

```
var form = document.forms.commentForm;

  var formData = new FormData(form);  
  alert(formData);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "*url php скрипта*");

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if(xhr.status == 200) {
        data = xhr.responseText;
        if(data != '0') {
          $(".background-load").fadeOut();
          localStorage['photo'] = data;
          $(".upload-file").fadeOut();
          mainView.router.load({pageName: 'somee'});
        }
      }
    }
  };

  xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: А разве это сжатие? Это ресайз изображения, то есть изменение его размеров по вертикали/горизонтали.

Comment: Ну мне бы хоты бы элементарный ресайз) @Visman

Comment: Автор, поправьте вопрос. У вас не php код в вопросе...

Comment: @GrayHoax прошу прощения, поправил

Comment: Не понятно, что именно вы отправляете на сервер. Файл, загруженный через input type="file"? Или битмап из канваса?

Comment: Через input type="file"

Comment: @Ilia Dementiev, Зайдите на страницу проекта http://gokercebeci.com/dev/canvasresize и посмотрите как это работает. Я имею в виду ресайз. Через инструменты разработчика в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, например: https://github.com/rossturner/HTML5-ImageUploader. Взято из enSO,
где [есть еще решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333971/html5-pre-resize-images-before-uploading).

Альтернативно можете просто [запретить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation) закачивать файлы не-JPG и больше N мегабайтов.